# How do I change the song in the spotify embed iframe player?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

I am building a website for podcasts and I have run into a problem. I am able to get the spotify id for the desired podcast but im not able to switch it with the player.

The track variable contains the desired podcast's spotify id.

```
import FlexBetween from "./FlexBetween";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Player = () => {
  const track = useSelector((state) => state.auth.currentTrack);
  console.log(track);
  window.onSpotifyIframeApiReady = (IFrameAPI) => {
    const element = document.getElementById("embed-iframe");
    const options = {
      uri: track,
    };
    const callback = (EmbedController) => {};
    IFrameAPI.createController(element, options, callback);
  };

  return (
    <FlexBetween
      style={{
        display: "inline-flex",
        width: "30%",
        padding: "2rem",
      }}
    >
      <FlexBetween id="embed-iframe" style={{}}></FlexBetween>
    </FlexBetween>
  );
};

export default Player;
```

I tried to use useEffect Hook but it is not working. I have nearly done designing the websites and designed other parts of the code, so it is really hard to restructure the entire project.